# FullText Contains "AND DO"

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I found a weird issue with a query that uses FullText index.

The following query

```
#1 SELECT * FROM tbparticipant where contains([FullTextQuery],'ALINE AND NASCIMENTO')
```

returns

```
ALINE DO NASCIMENTO
ALINE QUEIROZ DO NASCIMENTO                       
ALINE NASCIMENTO DE SOUZA
ALINE CORREIA DO NASCIMENTO
```

But this query

```
#2 SELECT * FROM tbparticipant where contains([FullTextQuery],'ALINE AND DO')
```

returns nothing.

I thought it would be a problem with "DO" being too short, but this query

```
#3 SELECT * FROM tbparticipant where contains([FullTextQuery],'ALINE AND DE')
```

returns

```
ALINE NASCIMENTO DE SOUZA
```

So, what's wrong with the query #2?

Comment: Perhaps "DO" is a reserved word in parsing `contains()` statement. Probably quoting "DO" in query will do.

Comment: I thought that too but I did some googling and found nothing about it. Quoting didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do" is on stopword list - stopwords are words considered to common or to short to have any significant meaning for full text queries. You can list your stopwords for english language like this:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords where language_id = 1033
```

Reference:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx

Comment: Yes that's it! But since I'm using SQL 2005, "do" is actually a "noise word" and it is located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData\noiseENG.txt file. I guess I have to do some replace magic before search. Thanks a lot!